# Hyperlink a sheet to index page containing $ sign

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am unable to hyperlink sheets containing $ in the sheetname to index page. 
I am referring the anchor to one cell of an Index page where the sheetname is stored.

```
For Each wsheet In Worksheets
    Set link = Cells.Find(wsheet.Name, LookIn:=xlvlalues, Lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns)
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=link, Address:="", subadress:=wsheet.Name & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=wsheet.Name
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `$` from the sheet name?

Comment: yes it does. But I want to hyperlink the name as is.

Comment: See answer in linked question - you need to surround the sheet name with single quotes. Your current code would also fail to create a link to a sheet that has whitespace in its name, for that reason.